# Dynamic routing based on http headers custom logic (Azure, AWS, GCP)

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, routes

I've a following scenario:

- there are 2 AKS clusters and I'd like to be able to route a request to any of those clusters based on a value from http headers. For example, let's say that a header has a specific value, which I can use to decide (applying custom logic) to which cluster I should route the request.

I've checked available cloud solutions, and the only one that may work is Lambda@Edge.
Just wondering, maybe there are some alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud’s HTTP(s) load balancers do facilitate routing traffic to different backends based on http headers.
And it can do so to various types of destinations like Google Kubernetes Engine, External endpoints of NEGs, VMs, App Engine etc.
You can further use NEGs and URL maps to direct traffic to further destinations.

Refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-query-and-header-routing#http-header-based-routing) for detailed instructions on how to provision HTTP header based routing though GCP load balancer.
Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/traffic-management?hl=en#traffic_steering_header-based_routing) regarding header-based routing based on HTTP parameters.